# to set column name to row vaues in R

Tags: r

I have this type of table in R

```
April   Tourist
2018     123
2018     222
```

I want my table to look like this:-

```
Month   Year  Domestic  International  Total
April   2018   123       222            345
```

I am new to R. I tried using melt and rownames() function given by R but not getting exactly the way out.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow :). Please, try to make your code reproducible and put it into chunks such that people can understand your question better and reproduce it. A a matter of a fact, I do not understand the format of your data, but to put column names in a data.frame, it is colnames(dataframe)<- c("Month", "Year",...)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. My table is having column name as "April" I want April to become a row value and column name "April" Should be renamed to "Year".

Comment: Your data does not say which row is domestic and international. While I can tell from your example I think you forgot to include that column in your example data set.

Comment: I want Tourist column to be separated in 2 different columns being domestic and international and the first value in tourist should go to domestic column and second value should go to international column

Comment: @supriyasingh Do you only have 2 rows in your actual data?

Comment: Yes. I need April column to be converted into row value  and that should have column name as Month. Column name April should be changed to Year. And another requirement is for Tourist column that I explained earlier.

Comment: @supriyasingh see my updated answer based on fact that you only have 2 rows in your data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment that you only have 2 rows in your data set here's a way to do this with `dplyr` and `tidyr` -

```
df <- data_frame(April = c(2018, 2018),
                 Tourist = c(123, 222))

df %>%
  mutate(Type = c("Domestic", "International")) %>%
  gather(Month, Year, April) %>% 
  spread(Type, Tourist) %>% 
  mutate(
    Total = Domestic + International
  )

# A tibble: 1 x 5
  Month  Year Domestic International Total
  <chr> <dbl>    <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>
1 April  2018      123           222   345
```

Comment: Thanks for response. But I don't want to make a separate dataframe. I have a table  like this:-
April    Tourist
2018    2,886.4
2018    613               and I want to mutate my table in such way to get desired output.

Comment: what do you mean you don't want separate dataframe? Are you referring to the `Type`column that I added?

Comment: Just wanted to know is there any other way without using data_frame. Can we use melt in this.

Comment: Actually I am scrapping a pdf file and then getting that table with 2 rows. Suppose that table is called April_table. I want this table to be used and converted into the required format. I don't want to use data_frame as this not using the table directly instead we are giving the value explicitly

Comment: Just make sure `April_table` is a `data.frame` (maybe try using `as.data.frame()`). No need to use `data_frame`.